# Add function on windows.load works only on the same javascript

Tags: javascript, onload-event

Why this script :

```
function addLoadEvent(func) {
    var existing = window.onload;


    window.onload = function () {
        if (typeof (existing) == "function") {
            existing();
        }
        func();
    };

}
```

works only from the js file where the "func()" resides?
How can i abstract this script?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what your question is, could you clarify, and perhaps give an example or use case? If you just want to split your javascript into "modules" You can import your javascript file through a ``<script>`` tag, or using a module loader like [require js](http://requirejs.org/). Then functions from other files/modules will be available.

Comment: no the problem is: html page with a single js file with the above function and the call to te above function works, html page with the above function in a separate file and the call to the above function in another file doesn't work. The function gets fired but all the reference to html elements in the function passed as parameters  throws null exception

Comment: What is func, the variable that I pass in the fuction?

Answer (score 0):

You try to change the tag `<script></script>` at `<script type="text/javascript"></script>`.

Comment: I know a friend called "Fabio Cianfarani" do you know? However i  don't understand you: if i put this script function addLoadEvent(func) {
    var existing = window.onload;


    window.onload = function () {
        if (typeof (existing) == "function") {
            existing();
        }
 addLoadEvent(Init)       ;function init(){} and then in the html page <script src=".js file"> it works but if in the html page i put this <script type...>function addLoadEvent(func) {
   ...

}</script> and then <script src="filewherefuncinitis.js"></script> doesn't work

Comment: Wait!!!
Your try with this tag:
<script type="text/javascript">.....</script>
Your live in Rome? (italy)